# Headless Browser and scraping - solutions

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to put list of possible solutions for browser automatic tests suits and headless browser platforms capable of scraping.

---

**BROWSER TESTING / SCRAPING:**

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) - **polyglot** flagship in browser automation, bindings for Python, Ruby,  JavaScript, C#, Haskell and more, IDE for Firefox (as an extension) for faster test deployment. Can act as a Server and has tons of features.

**JAVASCRIPT**

- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) - **JavaScript**, headless testing with screen capture and automation, uses **Webkit**. As of version 1.8 Selenium's WebDriver API is implemented, so you can use any WebDriver binding and tests will be compatible with Selenium
- [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) - similar to PhantomJS, uses **Gecko** (Firefox) instead of **WebKit**
- [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) - **JavaScript**, build on both PhantomJS and SlimerJS, has extra features
- [Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) - **JavaScript** implementation of the **WebDriver Wire Protocol** for **PhantomJS**.
- ***new*** [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) - CSS regression testing. A CasperJS module for automating visual regression testing with PhantomJS and [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/).
- ***new*** [WebdriverCSS](https://github.com/webdriverjs/webdrivercss) - plugin for [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io) for automating visual regression testing
- ***new*** [PhantomFlow](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomFlow) - Describe and visualize user flows through tests. An experimental approach to Web user interface testing.
- ***new*** [trifleJS](http://triflejs.org/) - ports the PhantomJS API to use the Internet Explorer engine.
- ***new*** [CasperJS IDE](https://gum.co/casperjside) *(commercial)*

**NODE.JS**

- [Node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom) - bridges the gap between **PhantomJS** and **node.js**
- [WebDriverJs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) - Selenium WebDriver bindings for node.js by Selenium Team
- [WD.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) - node module for WebDriver/Selenium 2
- [yiewd](https://github.com/jlipps/yiewd) - WD.js wrapper using latest Harmony generators! Get rid of the callback pyramid with **yield**
- [ZombieJs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) - Insanely fast, headless full-stack testing using **node.js**
- [NightwatchJs](http://nightwatchjs.org/) - Node JS based testing solution using Selenium Webdriver
- [Chimera](https://github.com/deanmao/node-chimera) - Chimera: can do everything what phantomJS does, but in a full JS environment
- [Dalek.js](http://dalekjs.com) - Automated cross browser testing with JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver
- [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io) - better implementation of WebDriver bindings with predefined 50+ actions
- [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) - Electron bridge with a high-level API.
- [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) - Tailored towards web scraping. A very lightweight DOM implemented in Node.js, it supports pages with javascript.
- ***new*** [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) - Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium. Puppeteer runs headless by default.

**WEB SCRAPING / MINING**

- [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) - **Python**, mainly a scraper/miner - fast, well documented and, can be linked with [Django Dynamic Scraper](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for nice mining deployments, or [Scrapy Cloud](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud.html) for PaaS (server-less) deployment, works in terminal or an server stand-alone proces, can be used with **Celery**, built on top of **Twisted**
- [Snailer](https://github.com/matthewhudson/snailer) - **node.js** module, untested yet.
- [Node-Crawler](https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler.git) - **node.js** module, untested yet.

**ONLINE TOOLS**

- ***new*** [Web Scraping Language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wslang) - Simple syntax to crawl the web
- ***new*** [Online HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637452/363573) - Dedicated SO answer
- ***dead*** [CasperBox](https://www.casperbox.com) - Run **CasperJS** scripts online

**Android TOOLS for Automation**

- ***new*** [Mechanica Browser App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tools.automate.browser.mechanica)

---

**RELATED LINKS & RESOURCES**

- [Comparsion of Webscraping software](http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2010/06/28/comparison-of-web-scraping-software/)
- ***new*** [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) : Image analysis and comparison

**Questions:**

- Any pure Node.js solution or Nodejs to PhanthomJS/CasperJS module that actually works and is documented?

**Answer:** Chimera seems to go in that direction, checkout [Chimera](https://github.com/deanmao/node-chimera)

- Other solutions capable of easier JavaScript injection than Selenium?
- Do you know any pure **ruby** solutions?

**Answer:** Checkout the list created by rjk with ruby based solutions

- Do you know any related tech or solution?

**Feel free to edit this question and add content as you wish!** Thank you for your contributions!

Comment: dont know if thats what you want, but i like that module for crawling webpages, inspecting the dom and so on: https://npmjs.org/package/crawler. it uses jsdom, and you can jQuery as selector-engine. this one (which uses crawler) looks interesting too: https://npmjs.org/package/snailer

Comment: I've had a lot of success with the node-phantom module. It's pretty straight forward and fairly well documented. It does support javascript injection.

Comment: I am sure you are aware that GhostDriver is an implementation of Selenium-Webdriver that uses phantomJS

Comment: You might also find this helpful: http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2010/06/28/comparison-of-web-scraping-software/

Comment: For visual scraping and comparisons: PhantomCSS and PhantomFlow

Comment: [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io) also has a CSS regression plugin called [WebdriverCSS](https://github.com/webdriverjs/webdrivercss) for visual scraping and comparison

Comment: http://github.com/briankircho/browserjet

Comment: Check this out, https://github.com/christian-bromann/awesome-selenium

Comment: I'm working on https://testingbot.com which has all the latest and older browsers, you can use selenium webdriver and test on any browser you like

Comment: There's also a list of solutions at https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers

Comment: USE import.io .

Comment: This one is really cool - https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless

Answer (score 36):

If Ruby is your thing, you may also try:

- https://github.com/chriskite/anemone (dev stopped)
- https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize
- https://github.com/postmodern/spidr
- https://github.com/stewartmckee/cobweb
- http://watirwebdriver.com/ (Selenium)

also, Nokogiri gem can be used for scraping:

- http://nokogiri.org/

there is a dedicated book about how to utilise nokogiri for scraping by packt publishing

Comment: watir is a thousand times easier than the libraries above.

Comment: For python "webbot" library offers rich features for easy web automation.

Answer (score 11):

http://triflejs.org/ is like phantomjs but based on IE

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That sounds good normally, yet this question is itself a collection of resources. A link with a short description to be incorporated in the list fits the format and makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

A kind of JS-based Selenium is [Dalek.js](http://dalekjs.com/). It not only aims for automated frontend-tests, you can also do screenshots with it. It has webdrivers for all important browsers. Unfortunately those webdrivers seem to be worth improving (just not to say "buggy" to Firefox).