# Front-end integration testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, integration-testing, frontend

I'm looking into doing some front-end integration testing and getting a little stuck on this.
I know how to do javascript unit tests, but I'm not really getting the idea of front-end testing.

Some scenarios I would like to test:

- After page load, can I check if a specific div is filled with content
- After clicking a button, a popup should show up, is this possible to test
- Does a div has specific HTML applied to it?

What would be the best tools to use? And how would I go ahead with this?

Comment: Selenium or Jasmine would work for those scenarios.

Comment: @Kyo, Thanks, checking out Jasmine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also would recommend e2e tests to check if your website and especially your javascript behaves like you'ld expect. There are a bunch of libraries you can use to do Webdriver tests in Javascript. Check out this stackoverflow thread: [Headless Browser and scraping - solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions).

For instance in [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io) you can easily chain several commands to navigate in the browser and get informations to test against. One of your scenarios could look like this (using Mocha):

```
describe("check if overlay pops up", function() {
  it("opens success overlay when I click on submit", function(done) {
    browser
      // show overlay
      .click(".btn_submit")
      .isVisible("#overlay", function(err,overlayIsOpen) {
        assert(err === null);
        assert(overlayIsOpen === true);
      })
      // hide overlay
      .click(".btn_ok")
      .isVisible("#overlay", function(err,overlayIsOpen) {
        assert(err === null);
        assert(overlayIsOpen === false);
      })
      .call(done)
  });

  // other tests
})
```

You will find a lot of other commands and examples on the project website. You can run these tests on several browser like Chrome, Firefox or even on mobile devices. Other popular libraries like [Wd.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) or [Selenium-Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) are promise based and do more or less the same.

Comment: To get back to this, what if there is an animation on #overlay, should I just put in a pause? Or is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I end up writing a few methods like "wait_for_visibility" and using these when clicking on modals.

Comment: But your `wait_for_visibilty` will still need to contain a pause somehow?

Comment: In the test you should not use Cypress code. Only use DLS layer

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the use of [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for front-end integration testing. The corresponding utility uses mocha-chai test suite to create and evaluate test cases on a web-page in a very easy and straight-forward way. Moreover, you may execute your tests from a command-line or a GUI where a video is been displayed and it can also record each of the tests. Here is a small sample:

```
describe('Test myProjects input fields', function () {
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://webpage.link/go/alink')
})

it('fills Project form', () => {
    cy.contains('Where is your item located?')

    cy.get('myelement-component-autocomplete[myelement="myProject/Home/hotelName"]').within(() => {
        cy.get('input').type('Hilton')
    })

    cy.get('myelement-component-datetime[myelement="myProject/Home/departureDate"]').within(() => {
        cy.get('input').type('2/4/2019')
    })
})
}
```

Later on, you can add it in your projects CI pipeline and every time you push changes the front-end test will be evaluated too.

Answer (score 1):

The two tools that I use for these purposes are PhantomJS + Mocha, or Selenium Webdriver.

If you want to test what actual users will see I would use Webdriver. PhantomJS is a headless browser. Webdriver actually drives a real browser (Chrome, Firefox etc).

A code example, using Python

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# at this point a chrome window will open
browser.get('http://example.com')

div = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.my-class')

assert div.text == 'The content I want to be there'
```

I see there are also JavaScript bindings now (of course). This page provides a good overview of getting everyhing installed: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a good push in the right direction, I prefer Selenium over PhantomJS though, just because it shows me what other users will see.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like kinda hidden knowledge, but in fact it's quite simple.

Integrations tests for the Frontend have best value. You use UI elements for interaction and intercept calls to the Backend and validate if they reflect what you've done. You also stub server responses so you can simulate different scenarios without having to configure the real backend server.

You can do it with Cypress in E2E mode (but don't do real e2e, because this kind of tests are too fragile and hard).

E.g.:

```
// Cypress logic is hidden. 
// Tests are in BDD style
// DSL layer is responsible for changing "user actions" into "app actions"
// there are no notion of "buttons", "style" etc in the test case itself

describe('Show User History', () => {

  // usersPage is a page object that sits in DSL layer. Only it interacts with Cypress
  const usersPage = new UsersPage();

  it('Should open users page', () => {
    //Given
    const user1 = UserBuilder().WithName("John", "Smith"); 

    const usersResponse = UsersBuilder()
      .withUser(user1)
      .withUser("Anna", "Smith")
      .build();

    usersPage.respondsWithUsers(usersResponse);
     
    // When
    usersPage.visit();

    // Then
    usersPage.shouldHaveEntriesCount(2);
    usersPage.shouldContain(user1);
  });
});
```