# How to download images from html page that uses javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I do program to parse html pages and store images. But I ran into a problem. This page is dynamically generated by JavaScript, it means when I download the source code of the page and there are links to pictures. Can you please advise how to bypass it? Alternatively, some příkalad to be in Java. thank you

Downloading page:
http://www.lide.cz/detail/j0YbgS6Xp7AoMAOP

Comment: Why is this off-topic? What additional information could you possibly need? I understand that the question is very high level, but one must start somewhere... And the problem is defnitely not about source code.

Answer (score 2):

That is not as easy as it seems to be at first glance. You need a headless browser engine like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) or the like that runs the Javascript and returns you the generated HTML.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions) to get more information on that topic.