# Scraping with Beautiful Soup: Why won't the get_text method return the text of this element?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Lately I've been working on a project in python that involves scraping a few websites for some proxies. The problem I'm running into with this is that when I try to scrape a certain well known proxy site, Beautiful Soup doesn't do what I expect when I ask it to find where the IPs are in the table of proxies. I'll attempt to scape for the IPs for each proxy, and I'll get outputs like this when I use Beautiful Soup's `.get_text()` method on the appropriate element.

```
...

.UbZT{display:none}
.f5fa{display:inline}
.Glj2{display:none}
.cUce{display:inline}
.zjUZ{display:none}
.GzLS{display:inline}
98120169.117.186373161218218.83839393101138154165203242 

...
```

Here's the element that I'm trying to parse (the td tag which contains the IP):

```
<td><span><style>
.lLXJ{display:none}
.qRCB{display:inline}
.qC69{display:none}
.V0zO{display:inline}
</style><span style="display: inline">190</span><span class="V0zO">.</span><span 
style="display:none">2</span><div style="display:none">20</div><span 
style="display:none">51</span><span style="display:none">56</span><div 
style="display:none">56</div><span style="display:none">61</span><span 
class="lLXJ">61</span><div style="display:none">61</div><span 
class="qC69">110</span><div 
style="display:none">110</div><span style="display:none">135</span><div 
style="display:none">135</div><span class="V0zO">221</span><span 
style="display:none">234</span><div style="display:none">234</div><span class="147">.
</span><span style="display: inline">29</span><div style="display:none">44</div><span 
style="display:none">228</span><span></span><span class="qC69">248</span>.<span 
style="display:none">7</span><span></span><span style="display:none">44</span><span 
class="qC69">44</span><span class="qC69">80</span><span></span><span 
style="display:none">85</span><span class="lLXJ">85</span><div 
style="display:none">85</div><span class="qC69">100</span><div 
style="display:none">100</div><span></span><span class="qC69">130</span><div 
style="display:none">130</div><div style="display:none">168</div>212<span 
style="display:none">230</span><span class="qC69">230</span><div 
style="display:none">230</div></span></td>
```

The actual text of this element is simply the IP for the proxy.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
# Hide My Ass
pages = ['https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list']

for page in pages:
    hidemyass = Soup(requests.get(page).text)
    rows = hidemyass.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name=='tr' and tag.has_attr('class'))
    for row in rows:
        fields = row.find_all('td')
        # get ip, port, and protocol for proxy
        ip = fields[1].get_text()            # <-- Here's the above td element
        port = fields[2].get_text()
        protocol = fields[6].get_text().lower()
        # store proxy in database
        db.add_proxy({'ip':ip,'port':port,'protocol':protocol})
        num_found += 1
```

Is there a correct way to parse this element so that the output won't get jumbled up like this? It seems intuitive that Beautiful Soup's `.get_text()` method would return exactly the text that is visible on the site, but I suppose that's not true. Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` cannot distinguish visible text from other text in the HTML markup. This particular website does a very good job of obfuscating the markup and makes web-scraping of the page more complex. You can try to understand what text is visible but it's not that easy since there are a lot of irrelevant elements being inserted that can be directly made invisible via `style` or via the `class`. Some of the `IP` parts are in `span`s, some of them are not a part of any tag.

One workaround would be to use [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which can grab only `visible` text from the element. For example, this code will print you all the `IP`s in the particular table:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver

browser = webdriver.WebDriver()
browser.get('https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list')

rows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="listtable"]//tr')
for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    print cells[1].text

browser.close()
```

See also:

- [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to use selenium, since it would be pretty clunky for just scraping.

Comment: +1: I looked into the Javascript of this site and it's really smart. It targets the specific classes, ids, or other attributes and strips them. I tried circumventing the JS, but too much overhead. Selenium indeed is a much better approach.

Comment: @Nanashi yeah, thanks. I was suprised to see how much is involved in obfuscating the data. You don't see this every day. :)

Comment: @Gold- note that you can use a "headless" browser with selenium, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions) and [this](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/).

Comment: @alecxe: Well, if you're a site that provides a service to obfuscate IP tracking, then I'd be more secure in the thought that you even thought of obfuscating your site! Pretty smart. I have to consider an event like this in the future when I scrape a site. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to parse Hidemyass.com code some time ago (this is Perl and parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad approach):

```
sub find_ip {

  my ($html) = @_;
  my $ip;

  my ($style_section) = $html =~ m{<style>(.+?)</style>};

  my (@bad_styles) = $style_section =~ m/

    \.(\w+)\s*\{display:\s*none\}
  /isxg;

  my $bad_styles = join("|", @bad_styles);

  $html =~ s{<div .+? </div>}{}isxg;
  $html =~ s{<span style="display:none">.+?</span>}{}g;
  $html =~ s{<style>.+?</style>}{};
  $html =~ s{^<span>|</span>$}{}g;
  $html =~ s{<span class="(?:$bad_styles)">.+?</span>}{}g;
  $html =~ s{</?[^>]+>}{}g;

  $ip = $html;

  return $ip;
}
```