# Web scraping python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to use this code to extract the urls but I can't get the google maps url shown in html. It returns 'None' when i try to find the url in this segment.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="http://www.example.com"
html=urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    print(tag['href'])



<div class="map_container">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 450px; margin-top: 10px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; -webkit-  transform: translateZ(0px);">
        <div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">...</div>
            <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/mapsll=28.535959,77.146119&amp;z=14&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;">
                    <div style="width: 62px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;">...</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript is probably needed in rendering the page you are trying to scrape. In that case, a `urllib` request will not render that page exactly as you see it in the browser. You will need to use `Selenium` for that.

Comment: Does changing `soup=BeautifulSoup(html)` to `soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` help?

Comment: How are you trying to find the tag attribute? It looks like it's there to me.. The `<a>` tag, right?

Comment: @alecxe changing soup=BeautifulSoup(html) to soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') didn't help.

Comment: @aIKid yes i'm using `<a>` tag

Comment: @user3612315 install `lxml` module and try with ` soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')`. Let me know if it helps or not. Thanks.

Comment: @user3612315 I'm still hoping there is no javascript involved in the loading this particular `a` tag (since no website link provided).

Comment: @alecxe Wow, looks like you're on fire recently.

Comment: @alecxe website link [link](http://www.zomato.com/ncr/monkey-bar-vasant-kunj-delhi/maps#tabtop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that this `maps.google.com` link is a part of a `div` with `id="map_canvas"` that is constructed using javascript. `urllib` (or `urllib2`) loads the page with an empty `map_canvas` div:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = "http://www.zomato.com/ncr/monkey-bar-vasant-kunj-delhi/maps#tabtop"
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
>>> print doc.find('div', id='map_canvas')
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:450px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
```

This means that you cannot easily get the link using the tools you are using now.

An alternative solution would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get(url)
>>> link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="map_canvas"]//a')
>>> link.get_attribute('href')
u'http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=28.536562,77.147664&z=14&t=m&hl=en&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3'
```

Comment: can it be made faster? opening up firefox and loading takes too much time, I have a list of pages from where the google maps url is to be extracted.

Comment: @user3612315 you can make use of a headless browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions and http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs