# How to get hidden data in a HTML file

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, sgmlreader

I try to get comments of a **Instagram** post with `C#`. But the thing is there is this ***'Load more comments'*** button which as it refers does its job and when i take a look a Firefox HTML codes all of the sudden new `<li>` element appears out of no where. Is this data getting there from a Database or it's embedded in HTML file? Is there a way to reach that data? I tried `SgmlReader` but i couldn't manage get all of the data that i'm looking for.

Comment: use selenium to click on the button to load more comments then you should be able to see the data

Comment: Try reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130650/scraping-data-dynamically-generated-by-javascript-in-html-document-using-c-sharp). I think it will help you.