# Python library to manipulate a website?

Tags: python, web

*I've tried searching the Internet for something that might do what I want, but I don't think I'm using the right search terms. I'm sure something like this must exist.*

My use case is this: I have a debit card, which spends money from my account directly. I usually try to keep this account manually at a certain balance, which means I have to log in to the bank website every few days and transfer money from my savings account into the debit account. Since it's always the same procedure - log in, read balance, transfer money to take balance back to threshold - I thought there surely must be some way to automate this. Every time I've tried to do something in Python, I've found a library for it :P so I figured it must be possible.

**So, my question:** Does there exist any way to use Python (or any language I suppose) to virtually view a web page as though it was in Firefox, and to then interact with that web page? I'd need to be able to do some sort of string searching I suppose, in order to find the required fields and buttons. It will be for a bank website, so I can't just load a HTML file statically and scan through it, it has to pretend it is an actual web browser (at least I imagine it would).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headless Browser and scraping - solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions)

Comment: The queries "Python Web automation", "Python Web automation library" should give you the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for module `Selenium` - doc: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Comment: ... which is also available for other languages like Java or C#