# Unable to install PhantomJS

Tags: server, phantomjs, libraries

I am working on a project which needs PhantomJS for scraping ajax content. It is working pretty well in my local pc which has Windows 8.1 OS and using apache local server. I got a shared server for running this project remotely. The shared server has CentOS 6.2. When I am running phantomjs it is asking for fontconfig and freetype libraries but it is not possible to install it on a shared server. Is there any way to do it? Is there any alternative to PhantomJS?

Comment: Please put whatever error message you are getting, on the question.

Comment: phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headless Browser and scraping - solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions)

Comment: It seems the is no way of using PhantomJS. Note that recommendation requests are off topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

PhantomJs is a Headless Browser and you can find the list of Headles Browsers in the link:

[Headless Browser and scraping - solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions)

Comment: It is hard to install PhantomJs except Ubuntu in Linux Operation Systems. You should be a linux expert to build PhantomJs on Centos, Suse etc. My recommendation is if it is not required use other options. If required get help to install determined tools(libfreetype is one of them).