# What tools should I use Selenium or nightwatch or other to automate data entry on few similar websites at the same time?.

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, watin, zombie.js, nightwatch.js

I  need to enter pretty much the same date on few handful of similar sites using web automation tools/ software. I am not doing testing I just want to use automation side of the tools. I need to enter the data same time ( as real time as possible ). I am wondering if one tool has advantage over other as I am using it just for automation.

Comment: Why not use a synchro browsing tool like BrowserSync (in ghost mode) ? http://www.browsersync.io/

Comment: Never heard of that. Will look into it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headless Browser and scraping - solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions)