# Prefill an external HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autofill

I am trying to find a way to prefill an external HTML form with data and then click "Submit" using Javascript. I do not own the website that the form is on, so that makes things difficult. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Define "external". Is it embedded within an iframe? Are you accessing it through a Java client?

Answer (score 1):

You actually can`t *click* other people's website using JavaScript. Maybe you can try something using an AJAX calls to send info but its out of the scope of this answer.

If you really plan to *click Submit* on someone's else form, you can look to [headless browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions) to fill this purpose. They can access the DOM and manipulate events such as click, load, etc.