# How to scrape table within a <script> tag that doesn't output in: soup = page.content ?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using `beautiful soup 4` and `requests` to scrape some information from a site that requires a log-in.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "username"
password = "password"

login_url = "mywebsite.com/login"
url = "mywebsite.com/profile"

def main():
    with requests.Session() as s:

        # Get login csrf token
        result = s.get(login_url)
        tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
        authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='lt']/@value")))[0]
        execution = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='execution']/@value")))[0]
        _eventId = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_eventId']/@value")))[0]

        # Create payload
        payload = {
            "username": username, 
            "password": password, 
            "lt": authenticity_token,
            "execution": execution,
            "_eventId": _eventId
            }

        # Perform login
        r = s.post(login_url, data = payload, headers = dict(referer=login_url))

        # An authorized request
        page = s.get(url)

        # Make the soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='utf-8') 

        # With soup
        data = []

        table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':"basicList.wide"})

        table_body = table.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
        print(data)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem I am having is that my `page.content` which I pass into the `BeautifulSoup()` function in order to create my `soup`, does not contain the table that I want to scrape data from even though it is displayed on my screen and in the HTML inspect element. Here is the relevant output that results from doing `print(soup)` (it's actually way more than this but these are the parts just before and just after where the table *should* be.

```
<a id="p_StudentRegistrationWAGadget_WAR_StudentRegistrationWAGadgetportlet_INSTANCE_eiG4"/> 

<div class="portlet-borderless-container" style=""> 

<div class="portlet-body"> 

<div id="StudentRegistrationWAGadget3fe0ccfe435425a6"/> 

<script type="text/javascript"> /**/window.qkAppReady.done(function(){require(["qk"],function(a){a.mainSession.newGadget("WebAdvisorGadget",{initialScreen:"ST-XWESTS04C",enableOlark:true,container:"#StudentRegistrationWAGadget3fe0ccfe435425a6"})})});/**/</script> 

</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <form action="" id="hrefFm" method="post" name="hrefFm"/> </div> 

<!-- begin footer -->
```

And here are some images of the Inspect Element of the page, and specific table, I want to scrape. I've marked with arrows the relevant spots.

[HTML data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCC3y.png)

[HTML data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/396Kc.png)

I'm not really sure where I would start with solving this and any help is appreciated, especially information regarding what exactly I'm doing wrong or concepts that I am misunderstanding with scraping that are the underlying cause of my confusion. I don't even know if the title is accurately representing what my problem is as I don't know the language to explain why I can't access the table.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the text data you're looking for doesn't exist in the soup object, it's likely being rendered through javascript. If true, you'll need to either figure out what endpoint is being used to request the JS, or just use a browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions

Comment: @jrjames83 Is this something that a library like mechanicalsoup and their statefulBrowser class could help with?