# scraping dynamic webpages with nodesJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using nodeJs. I am fairly new to web scraping and I am more experienced in javascript. The problem I had is that websites that use dynamic contents like`iframes` and `ajax` calls need to be opened in a browser like environment to load the dynamic content.

how do I proceed to be able to load the dynamic content and get the data it provides using Javascript ?

Comment: You might want to look into PhantomJS.

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions