# How to extract Amazon Reviews?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, python-3.7

I want to extract amazon reviews and all its related data like: Name of reviewer, rating, content, and (if possible) comments in response to that review.
I am using python 3.7.

Comment: You can use selenium like tool or head less chrome

Comment: Thanks Rohit..
It helped me a lot. Now the issue remaining is to crawl star ratings against each review. Rather all information are extracted by your kind suggestion

Comment: you can simply ask for API from amazon that will be faster and reliable.

Comment: or if you don't have API then by using above method you can look for particular element in dom

Comment: I will try it.. as I have not a deep knowledge about API

Comment: I have added an answer, if you found it helpful please accept it

Comment: also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080584/is-it-legal-to-crawl-amazon?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by two methods:

1. API (reliable fast)

Ask for API from Amazon

2. Tools like Headless chrome or Selenium
   [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions?rq=1)

Find DOM element in the page like

```
<div id="R1IZDPP09RA69A" data-hook="review" class="a-section review">
    <div id="customer_review-R1IZDPP09RA69A" class="a-section celwidget" data-cel-widget="customer_review-R1IZDPP09RA69A">
        <div class="a-row a-spacing-mini">
            <a href="/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AGFB356ZQJQAHWZZABTTNIFGYMDA/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8" class="a-profile" data-a-size="small">
                <div aria-hidden="true" class="a-profile-avatar-wrapper">
                    <div class="a-profile-avatar">
                        <img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/amazon-avatars/f0d86e6d-45d4-4cc7-a4b8-a062450c2c75._CR0,0,335,335_SX48_.jpg" class="" data-src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/amazon-avatars/f0d86e6d-45d4-4cc7-a4b8-a062450c2c75._CR0,0,335,335_SX48_.jpg">
                        <noscript><img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/amazon-avatars/f0d86e6d-45d4-4cc7-a4b8-a062450c2c75._CR0,0,335,335_SX48_.jpg"></noscript>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="a-profile-content"><span class="a-profile-name">Sana Khanam</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="a-row"><a class="a-link-normal" title="4.0 out of 5 stars" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R1IZDPP09RA69A/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B079Q9VNWQ"><i data-hook="review-star-rating" class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4 review-rating"><span class="a-icon-alt">4.0 out of 5 stars</span></i></a><span class="a-letter-space"></span><a data-hook="review-title" class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R1IZDPP09RA69A/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B079Q9VNWQ">Amazing service by VOLTAS !!Appreciated </a></div>
        <span data-hook="review-date" class="a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date">17 May 2018</span>
        <div class="a-row a-spacing-mini review-data review-format-strip"><span data-hook="avp-badge-linkless" class="a-size-mini a-color-state a-text-bold">Verified Purchase</span></div>
        <div class="a-row a-spacing-small review-data">
            <span data-hook="review-body" class="a-size-base review-text">
                <div aria-live="polite" data-a-expander-name="review_text_read_more" data-a-expander-collapsed-height="300" class="a-expander-collapsed-height a-row a-expander-container a-expander-partial-collapse-container" style="max-height: none; height: 300px;">
                    <div data-hook="review-collapsed" aria-expanded="false" class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content" style="padding-bottom: 19px;">5 th day after having AC installed.<br>PROS:<br><br>-Cooling nice<br>-Looks good<br>-Good one in this price range<br>-Fast Installation within 24h<br>- Customer support response appriciated<br><br>CONS<br>-Started making weird little noises while decreasing temperature.<br><br>-I don't understand but some unpleasant smell being diffused after starting it at the 5th day of installation.<br><br>-Contacted seller, issue resolved!<br><br>Overall would RECOMMEND!! Go for  it.</div>
                    <div class="a-expander-header a-expander-partial-collapse-header" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
                        <div class="a-expander-content-fade"></div>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-hook="expand-collapse-read-more-less" data-action="a-expander-toggle" class="a-declarative" data-a-expander-toggle="{&quot;allowLinkDefault&quot;:true, &quot;expand_prompt&quot;:&quot;Read more&quot;, &quot;collapse_prompt&quot;:&quot;Read less&quot;}"><i class="a-icon a-icon-extender-expand"></i><span class="a-expander-prompt">Read more</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div data-hook="review-comments" class="a-row review-comments">
            <span class="cr-vote" data-hook="review-voting-widget">
                <div class="a-row a-spacing-small"><span data-hook="helpful-vote-statement" class="a-size-base a-color-tertiary cr-vote-text">5 people found this helpful</span></div>
                <div class="cr-helpful-button aok-float-left">
                    <span class="a-button a-button-base" id="a-autoid-14">
                        <span class="a-button-inner">
                            <a href="https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fdp%2FB079Q9VNWQ%2Fref%3Dcm_cr_dp_d_vote_lft%3Fie%3DUTF8%26voteInstanceId%3DR1IZDPP09RA69A%26voteValue%3D1%26csrfT%3DgiYnW3e%252Fv7p8y07m5Je2hA3LGXQ2gVKHQWzD%252F40AAAAJAAAAAFuvcotyYXcAAAAAFVfwLBerPie4v1Ep%252F%252F%252F%252F%23R1IZDPP09RA69A&amp;openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&amp;openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&amp;openid.assoc_handle=inflex&amp;openid.mode=checkid_setup&amp;openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0" data-hook="vote-helpful-button" class="a-button-text" role="button" id="a-autoid-14-announce">
                                <div class="cr-helpful-text">
                                    Helpful
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </span>
            <i class="a-icon a-icon-text-separator" role="img" aria-label="|"></i><a data-hook="review-comment" class="a-size-base a-link-normal a-color-secondary a-text-normal" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R1IZDPP09RA69A/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_btm?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B079Q9VNWQ#wasThisHelpful">Comment</a><span class="cr-footer-line-height">
            <span><i class="a-icon a-icon-text-separator" role="img" aria-label="|"></i><span class="a-declarative" data-action="cr-popup" data-cr-popup="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;580&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;ReportAbuse&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;/hz/reviews-render/report-abuse?ie=UTF8&amp;voteDomain=Reviews&amp;ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_hlp&amp;csrfT=giYnW3e%2Fv7p8y07m5Je2hA3LGXQ2gVKHQWzD%2F40AAAAJAAAAAFuvcotyYXcAAAAAFVfwLBerPie4v1Ep%2F%2F%2F%2F&amp;entityId=R1IZDPP09RA69A&amp;sessionId=257-1905223-9805712&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;380&quot;}"><a class="a-size-base a-link-normal a-color-secondary report-abuse-link a-text-normal" href="/hz/reviews-render/report-abuse?ie=UTF8&amp;voteDomain=Reviews&amp;ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_hlp&amp;csrfT=giYnW3e%2Fv7p8y07m5Je2hA3LGXQ2gVKHQWzD%2F40AAAAJAAAAAFuvcotyYXcAAAAAFVfwLBerPie4v1Ep%2F%2F%2F%2F&amp;entityId=R1IZDPP09RA69A&amp;sessionId=257-1905223-9805712">Report abuse</a></span></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here you can find reviewer name rating and review under each `div` having attribute `data-hook="review"`.

Name under `<span class="a-profile-name">Sana Khanam</span>`

Rating `<span class="a-icon-alt">4.0 out of 5 stars</span>`

Review `<div data-hook="review-collapsed" aria-expanded="false" class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content" style="padding-bottom: 19px;">5 th day after...</div>`

Comment: 1. review_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-hook="review-title"]')
2. review_content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="review-body"]')
3. review_date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="review-date"]')
4. helpful_vote = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]')
5. rating = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]')
No.5 is not working.. above 4 are working

Comment: look for <i data-hook="review-star-rating" class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4 review-rating">
                    <span class="a-icon-alt">4.0 out of 5 stars</span>
                </i>

Comment: @data-hook="review-star-rating" and then extract rating from that

Comment: @data-hook="review-star-rating" and then extract rating from that
still this is not giving the desired results

Comment: rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@data-hook="review-star-rating"]')

Now this is working but as I am getting values in text so these stars are not going to be converted in text. is there any way in python to get these stars or we can convert these to text??

Comment: Save them into numerical value, after that you can show them as graphics or text in html or any frontend

Comment: can you please brief that how will it be conveted to numerical?